# Integer limitations in a C++ calculator

Tags: c++

Integer limits my answer to `-2147483648` if I enter two large enough numbers. Can I substitute `double v1 = 0, v2 = 0` into my code? If I do so, is there a way to make it output the full length of the answer (not `5e+17` etc.)

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
cout << "Enter two numbers: " << endl;
int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
cin >> v1 >> v2;
int sum = 0, val = v1;

while (val <= v2)
{
    sum += val;
    ++ val;
}
cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " through " << v2 << " inclusive is " << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a 32 bit integer. You could use instead a 64 bit integer, `int64_t`. Or if you need more range than that then use a big integer class with arbitrary precision.

But I urge you not to use floating point arithmetic for integer calculations. That will just be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I substitute double v1 = 0, v2 = 0 into my code?

You can, but there are caveats which arise when you start using floating-point numbers. Watch out for them.

> is there a way to make it output the full length of the answer

You want to do some `iomanip`:

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed) << std::setprecision(2) << val;
```